# Toilet tank level rises slowly

Tags: toilet

Refill valve appears to work normally, shutting the water off at the correct level. Then several hours later the water level has risen to the top of the overflow pipe. What's going on here? If I shut the water supply off, the level doesn't go down even after a day, so I know the flapper seal is good

Comment: Depending on type of float, it might have a leak.  Picture of inside of the tank will help.

Answer (score 2):

> Refill valve appears to work normally

Nope, it just leaks slowly enough that you think that. It fills to level quickly, and then keeps filling slowly based on your problem statement.

You have a leak on the fill valve where the fill valve is not shutting **all** the way off.

Replace the fill valve (or waste probably more time and money than a new fill valve trying to find parts to rebuild your existing fill valve - your call.)

Answer (score 1):

Your fill valve isn't sealing tight and water is leaking into the tank. Just replace the fill valve, easier than trying to find parts plus you'll probably break something if you do try to replace parts.